# Wrong encoding in communication between php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, collation

Hello I bought this app code that uses data from sql database. There is no problem in english, but I need to use czech special signs like č,ř,š,ě,í,é.. I can alter the data using these czech signs in CMS without problem, but in sql database they are wrong (like é instead of č), when I alter the data in database its wrong in CMS (in different way č is ?) and than its of course wrong in android app also or it crashes because it does not recognize charset. I try to solve this for more than month, I have read everything here and on google, but still dont know where the problem is. I have even recreated whole database by hand and set up by hand for each table utf8, or utf8mb4. I have tried to add to function

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

but it has zero effect like I did not do anything

I have of course changed all the php files to utf8 or utf8mb4, but the errors are still the same. I did the same with database.

If I run

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%'
```

I get these results:

```
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/percona-server/charsets/
```

PHP Version 5.4.45

Thanks for any ideas or any help.

```
Update: SHOW CREATE TABLE returned:
    category    CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `institution_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `programme_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `question_time` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `limits` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `correct_ans_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `wrong_ans_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `expire_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `no_of_days` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin


category    CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `institution_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `programme_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `question_time` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `limits` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `correct_ans_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `wrong_ans_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `expire_date` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `no_of_days` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Abandon the `mysql_*` API; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mees Kluivers, there was some info indeed that helped me. I added these two lines to beginning of every PHP file and now it shows correct characters both in CMS and in mysql database, for some reason android app still shows ? instead of č, but its still huge step forward after month dealing with it.

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query("set charset 'utf8'");
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have converted to `mysqli_*` interface, use the `set_charset('utf8')` function.

Also, be sure that your column/table is declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

I would be happy to further diagnose your problem, but I need more info.  Is `č` turning into `?` or `Ä` or being truncated or perhaps something else.  I see no way for it to turn into `é`, so I need more clues.

Comment: As i wrote in the answer, PHP/mysql communication seems working ok after i added those two lines of code in every php file.  Now problem moved to the android app which still shows ? instead of č. however, if I add č directly in the code of the app, it shows č, it shows ? only when the data comes from mysql database. So if Im right, the whole problem is the database.

Comment: `?` usually comes from table definition being wrong.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Ok I have updated the question with result of SHOW CREATE TABLE from probably the most important table in the database.

Comment: What language (PHP / Java / etc) does Android talk to the database with?

Comment: The app project is in appcelerator studio (titanium studio), so it is java. The problem is I did not build the app, only bought it and there are ttitanium alloy things which I do not understand and cannot find in documentation how it connects to remote database, only found stuff about local sqlite database, not how it connects to remote sql database..

Comment: Ok I got it wrong, I found another PHP files in another folder which are probably used to communicate with the app, but after I changed it, č is not ?, but it is now %C4%8D, which looks very similar to UTF8 hex code for letter č, c4 8d.

Comment: `%C4%8D` would be the "url encoding" -- useful for safely passing 8-bit stuff in urls.  `C48D` will, I think, be correctly converted back into `č` by the receiving web page.

Comment: Any idea why does it do that? Im really confused why would it url encode normal text in database.

Comment: "It"?  MySQL never adds the `%`.  PHP adds them if you call `url_encode()`.  Is there any other product involved?

Comment: I found this in function.php function array_encode($arr)
{
   $en_arr=array();
  if(count($arr)>0)
  {    
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
    {   
   if(is_array($val))
      $en_arr[$key]=array_encode($val);
      else  
      $en_arr[$key]=urlencode($val);
    }
  }
  return $en_arr;
}
function array_decode($arr)
{
  if(count($arr)>0)
  {
   foreach ($arr as $key=>$val)
    {
   if(is_array($val))
      $de_arr[$key]=array_decode($val);  
   else   
      $de_arr[$key]=urldecode($val);
    }
  }
    return $de_arr;
}`code`

Comment: Sry for formatting, for some reason I cannot add it as code.

Comment: But why ever encode or decode?  That is, _when_ do you call those functions?

Comment: I do not know, i did not write the code, only bought it. i tried to find it. Looks like $arr is everywhere in the code, 690 matches exactly.

Comment: I have kinda solved it by replacing urlencode with urldecode. So far app seems working ok.